# Insert and update record with Ajax and Symfony2

Tags: ajax, jquery, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to insert/update a record in AJAX using Symfony2. I am submitting my form using JQuery. Here's my controller:

```
public function myEntitysAction(){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $request = $this->getRequest(); 
    $AJAXresponse = array();

    $myEntity = new myEntity();       
    $form = $this->createForm(new myEntityType(), $myEntity);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        $form->bindRequest($this->getRequest());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $AJAXResponse['code'] = 'OK';
            $em->persist($myEntity);        
            $em->flush();
        }else{          
            $AJAXResponse['code'] = 'ERR';  
        }

        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() == true) {
            $response = new Response(json_encode($AJAXResponse));
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return $response;
        }

    } 

}
```

The issue is that this code inserts fine, but I can't update the data; it keeps on inserting. Do I have to implement myself a way to update by sending the new ID back to the response or is there a way with Symfony to handle that automatically?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: That's because of the line `$myEntity = new myEntity();` if you want to do an update you've to load your entity from you database. But you want to create an entity and then be able to edit this entity without reloading the page that's it?

Comment: yes that's it. Not exactly sure how to do this besides sending the new Id to the client and resending it in the next ajax request for update.

Comment: i'm not sure you can do it without reloading the page. Maybe you can try to add an hidden field and push the id inside when it's an update and just add a rule in your form validation.

Comment: Yes I was trying to add the Id in the form builder with an attribute hidden but it wasn't working too well. It's very frustrating that there's no easier way to do this out of the box. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Must be a way to do it but i'm not sure this will be very clean... Tell us if you find the trick

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
//Firt, update your route (p. ex)
site_add:
    pattern:  /edit/add
    defaults: { _controller: YOURBUNDLE:YOURCONTROLLER:myEntitys }

site_update:
    pattern:  /edit/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: YOURBUNDLE:YOURCONTROLLER:myEntitys }


//Then in your controller

//...
public function myEntitysAction($id = null){

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$request = $this->getRequest();
$AJAXresponse = array();

//To modify
if(isset($id)){
    $myEntity = $em->find('YOURBUNDLE:YOURENTITY', $id);
}
//To create
else{
    $myEntity = new myEntity();
}
//Both return an objet

//Form will be render depeding on objet.
$form = $this->createForm(new myEntityType(), $myEntity);

if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

    $form->bindRequest($this->getRequest());

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $AJAXResponse['code'] = 'OK';
        $em->persist($myEntity);
        $em->flush();
    }else{
        $AJAXResponse['code'] = 'ERR';
    }

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() == true) {
        $response = new Response(json_encode($AJAXResponse));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
    }

}
```

}